# Bootstrap panel with responsive table inside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a JS Bin link: http://jsbin.com/qiziyupo/4/edit?output

The responsive table does not shrink to fit the panel. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution where the responsive table will resize to fit inside the panel, without having to make the panel larger.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `.table-responsive` class is only designed to be responsive on mobile devices...

*From the Bootstrap 3.1.1 documentation...*

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally up to small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables

But you  can add the class into your css without the media query and get the functionality at any viewport.

But note that this does not shrink the table, it only gives a horizontal scroll bar...

Below is the `.table-responsive` classes from Bootstrap without the media query restricting it to 768px and below.

```
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.table-responsive>.table { 
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th, 
.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

There are a few more CSS rules for `.table-bordered` that I did not include...

Comment: Cool. Works nicely also when collapsed to narrow device view. Even works for a table shown in bootbox dialog that is wrapped in div.table-responsive. Only changes were to use auto for overflow-x and to remove the border - border is provided by the dialog. I would also suggest to wrap any table inside a panel into div.row - that makes the table flow from left to right edge.

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I was looking for. I rename the class "table-responsive" to "table-responsive-custom" in order to avoid collisions with the original table-responsive Bootstrap class.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow:scroll">            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
```

Just write this for table horizontal scrolling in the panel body.

Comment: I've updated your post to include the code. You can read about code formatting on this site at http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2):

Better not to use panel-body, Put the table inside the panel tag, not to use Panel Body

Answer (score 0):

This happens beacuse Panel has this class:

```
.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

that force its width. Remove it and eveything will  be ok :-)

Comment: Thanks Luca, but this wasn't quite what I was looking for. I've edited my question to make things more clear.

Comment: You can't have what you desire, simply because you have content that requires a larger space than Panel width. As you see, you don't have "sentences" that may be wrap inside table cells, but only single words, that fill a specific space. If you can't enlarge your Panel, only solutions are reduce padding on table cells and font-size of each text... You'll be able to recover some space.....

Answer (score 0):

Using container also has an impact on it. If Your layout does not have fixed layout, use `container-fluid`, and there will not be any problem with responsiveness of `.table` class.